# Core Data error with string symbols register

Tags: ios, macos, core-data

I faced with strange Core Data behavior.

When I check my database with SQLIte Database Viewer I see "STRING" value. But when I read this value I get "String".

Code I use is reported below:

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init] autorelease];

//which entity (or table) to select data   
[request setEntity: [[mdl entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"KeyName"]];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *dataArray = [cntx  executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
```

How can it be? How data can be transformed during reading?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. What are you seeing that's unexpected? What question are you asking?

Comment: Provide some other details. Thanks.

Comment: I expect to read "STRING" from database (All capital letters). Howewer I read "String" from database. The question is why it happens?       Which additional info can I provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my application is Osirix DICOM viewer plugin.

Fortunately I get answer on Osirix Development Group conference

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/osirix-dev/message/3469

I use valueForKey method to get data from NSArray *dataArray array 
But the proper method here is primitiveValueForKey

valueForKey work with Osirix 4.x
Osirix 5.x has property "Display patient names and descriptions in Capitalized Words".
If this property is ON valueForKey doesn't work. 
We should use primitiveValueForKey  is this case.

```
NSArray *dataArray = [cntx  executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];

for( i ...  )
{
 DicomStudy *study = [dataArray objectAtIndex: i];
 NSString *myValue = [study primitiveValueForKey:myKey];

}
```